# MPAndroidChart time chart x-axis does not show all values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am developing an app in which I have used [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). It shows certain values against a particular month. The data is like this:

```
1430418600000, 130.279999\n1433097000000, 125.43\n1435689000000, 121.300003\n1438540200000, 112.760002\n1441045800000, 110.300003\n1443637800000, 119.50\n1446402600000, 118.300003\n1448908200000, 105.260002\n1451845800000, 97.339996\n1454265000000, 96.690002\n1456770600000, 108.989998\n1459449000000, 93.739998\n1462127400000, 99.860001\n1464719400000, 95.599998\n1467311400000, 104.209999\n1469989800000, 106.099998\n1472668200000, 113.050003\n1475433000000, 113.540001\n1477938600000, 110.519997\n1480530600000, 115.82\n1483381800000, 121.349998\n1485887400000, 136.990005\n1488306600000, 143.660004\n1491157800000, 143.649994
```

Now the `Y-Axis` is showing the max and min points as provided but x axis is showing just 6 points.

Chart initializing code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Contract.Quote.makeUriForStock(quote_symbol),
            Contract.Quote.QUOTE_COLUMNS.toArray(new String[]{}),
            null, null, Contract.Quote.COLUMN_SYMBOL);

if(cursor!=null)
{
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

// no description text
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

// enable touch gestures
chart.setTouchEnabled(true);

chart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);

// enable scaling and dragging
chart.setDragEnabled(true);
chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);

// set an alternative background color
chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
chart.setScaleXEnabled(true);

;
// set data
chart.setData(prepareLineData(cursor));

// do not forget to refresh the chart
chart.invalidate();
chart.animateX(750);
```

Preparing the chart data:

```
private LineData prepareLineData(Cursor cursor)
{
    String historyData=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Quote.COLUMN_HISTORY));
    String maxValueString=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Quote.COLUMN_HISTORY_MAX_VALUE));
    String maxDateString=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Quote.COLUMN_HISTORY_MAX_DATE));
    String minValueString=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Quote.COLUMN_HISTORY_MIN_VALUE));
    String minDateString=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Quote.COLUMN_HISTORY_MIN_DATE));

    String[] historyDataArray=historyData.split("\n");
    ArrayList<Entry> e1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < historyDataArray.length; i++) {
        String[] historyDataValues=historyDataArray[i].split(",");
        e1.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(historyDataValues[0]), Float.parseFloat(historyDataValues[1])));
    }

    Typeface mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");


    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 192, 56));
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(Float.parseFloat(maxDateString));
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(Float.parseFloat(minDateString));
    xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        private SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,yy");
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return mFormat.format(new Date((long) value));
        }
    });
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(Float.parseFloat(maxValueString)); 
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 192, 56));
    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
    LineDataSet d1 = new LineDataSet(e1, "Price");
    d1.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    d1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    d1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    d1.setDrawValues(false);
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    sets.add(d1);
    return new LineData(sets);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MPAndroidChart calculate the labels to show automatically.

If you want to show Labels at specific positions, you can use a modified version of the library.

See the example below:

```
leftAxis.setShowSpecificLabelPositions(true);
leftAxis.setSpecificLabelPositions(new float[]{0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 300});
```

You can download the library here: https://github.com/philippeauriach/MPAndroidChart/tree/custom-labels